# Unable to mount Drive1 - Not Authorized

Tags: server, partitioning, disk

I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04 on my HP Proliant microserver.

I am using `webmin/vnc/ssh` to administer it.

I'm trying to mount a drive which I had previously used on the same kit but with OpenMediaVault. In OMV I had formatted the disk as xfs.

When I try to access the disk in Ubuntu I get:

```
Unable to mount Drive1 - Not Authorized
```

I've tried mounting the disk in Webmin but it has no option for xfs.

I'm quite new to Linux so can anyone assist me?

Comment: sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb /mnt/Main results in error: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mount the entire disk (`/dev/sdb`) rather than a partition on the disk (such as `/dev/sdb1`).  Do you know which partition on the disk you need to mount?  It's probably sdb1, but not necessarily.